# Method returns before its end

Tags: java

I'm using latest eclipse. How is it possible that my method closes before its end or before a `return` statement?! The issue is not random, it fires only at certain lines, anyway sounds to me impossible. Compiler bug? I really don't know. Googling I found nothing.

```
default: {
        ColumnSelector.showMovieSelector(list, frame);
        break;
    }
```

My code just show a customized `JoptionPane.showOptionDialogue`:

```
public static int showMovieSelector(List<MovieDb> list,Component component) {
        JList<String> swinglist = new JList<>();
        String[] array = new String[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = list.get(i).getTitle();
        }
        swinglist.setListData(array);
        swinglist.setSelectedIndex(0);
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(list.get(0).getImages().get(0).getFilePath()));
        JLabel l1=new JLabel(img);
        JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, swinglist, l1);
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(component, pane, "", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
        return swinglist.getSelectedIndex();
    }
```

`Component component` is my customized JFrame, the `List` is an implementation of TheMovieDB API.

Comment: Show the code in question please.

Comment: Perhaps posting the code giving you issue might help you, else the question is going to be closed.

Comment: The code you posted is nice, but can we see the full context please?

Comment: Can you put some more details? Some code examples?

Comment: We can't help you fix what's wrong with the method if you don't post the code for the whole method.

Comment: What is the value it returns? Does it not return anything at all? Or are you not capturing the returned value (e.g., `int returnedValue = ColumnSelector.showMovieSelector(list, frame);`)? There's no reason `showMovieSelector()` should exit (without throwing an error) before `return`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the return anywhere before the end of your method then check you may be getting an exception, which may be causing your method to return abruptly.

Answer (score 0):

Half-solved. It came out that is a kind of bug in `getImages()`. If I surround it with a try-catch it throws an exception even if the source code SEEMS not to be supposed to do this. I'll investigate.